# summation of a particular series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need a little help in summing the the following series:

$$ 1+2v^4+3v^8+4v^{12}+\ldots + 20v^{76}?$$

---

Is there a closed formula for summing $$ \sum_{k=0}^{n} k\cdot ar^k?$$

Comment: $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k\cdot ar^k=ar\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}kr^{k-1}=ar\frac{d}{dr}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}r^k\right)= \frac{ar(r-r^n)}{1-r}$$ It’s been derived many times here, but I don’t immediately find an example

Comment: There are various approaches, but you could try here setting $x=v^4$. Then sum $x+x^2+x^3+ \dots$ and then differentiate both sides.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
S & = \sum_{k=1}^n akr^k = ar \sum_{k=1}^{n} k r^{k-1} = ar \dfrac{d}{dr} \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} r^{k}\right)\\
& = ar \dfrac{d}{dr} \left( \dfrac{r(r^n-1)}{r-1}\right) = ar \left(\dfrac{nr^{n+1} - (n+1)r^n + 1}{(r-1)^2} \right)
\end{align}

Comment: If you felt like it, you could factor that last bit to $$\frac{ar(nr-1)(r^n-1)}{(r-1)^2}.$$